# Google In App Billing on Android 1.5

Tags: android, in-app-billing, in-app-purchase

We are currently developing android application using Platform version 1.5 and facing to implement In App Billing below,

There are errors for IntentSender in PurchaseObserver.java

Is there any way we can implement Google In App Billing API with Platform version 1.5?
If we change platform version to 1.6, another screen size problem which is really hard to fix occurred.

Thank you

Comment: You'd need to post the actual errors to get any useful help.  BTW, most people these days write to a minimum version of at least 2.2, if not 2.3.  I'm not sure why you'd target 1.5, the version is long dead and you'll be missing lots of useful classes and features.  And if you're seeing screen size errors on 1.6, my guess is that you probably have issues porting between different sized devices on 1.5 as well.

Comment: Hi this project from conversion tools, original was JAVA, and if we target 1.6, There are a lots of screen size error and will take long time to be fixed... If we can use google in app billing API with 1.5, I'd like to do that.

Comment: Error on 1.5 for In app billing,  IntentSender.class, Intent.class, int.class, int.class, int.class in PurchaseObserver class..